# RuntimeError, wrong version of TBackward since updating SSH server, what can I do?

Tags: python, pytorch

currently working on my thesis using a PyTorch pix-2-pix model, the model has been running on an SSH server and has been updated recently. Since the update, I get the following error message when trying to run the code. Is there some way I can downgrade my user back to the 'old' version of TBackward?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-abea6d9413b2> in <module>()
     31         if update_G:
     32             optimizer_G.zero_grad()
---> 33             losses[1].backward(retain_graph=True)
     34             optimizer_G.step()
     35 

/home/u1269991/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    219                 retain_graph=retain_graph,
    220                 create_graph=create_graph)
--> 221         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    222 
    223     def register_hook(self, hook):

/home/u1269991/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
    130     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    131         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph,
--> 132         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    133 
    134 

RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [41472, 1]], which is output 0 of TBackward, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

The code errors around the losses. The code of the losses is as follows

```
def forward_n_get_loss(real_img, cond_img, G, D, c=100):
    #
    fake_img = G(cond_img) 
    real_pair = torch.cat(([real_img, cond_img]), 1)
    fake_pair = torch.cat(([fake_img, cond_img]), 1)
    prob_real, prob_fake = D(real_pair), D(fake_pair.detach())
    # loss_D
    loss_D_real = nn.BCELoss()(prob_real, torch.ones_like(prob_real))
    loss_D_fake = nn.BCELoss()(prob_fake, torch.zeros_like(prob_fake))
    loss_D = (loss_D_real + loss_D_fake) *0.5
    # loss_G
    loss_G_fake = nn.BCELoss()(prob_fake, torch.ones_like(prob_fake))
    loss_G_FLIP_l1 = FLIP_l1_loss(fake_img, real_img) 
    loss_G = loss_G_fake + c*loss_G_FLIP_l1 
    return loss_D, loss_G, loss_D_real, loss_D_fake, loss_G_fake, loss_G_FLIP_l1
```

Location where it performs the `backward` call.

```
# train!
import time
start_epo = 0
n_epochs = 20
print_freq = 10
st = time.time()
loss2npval = lambda loss : np.mean(loss.cpu().data.numpy()).round(4)
loss_names = ["loss_D", "loss_G", "loss_D_real", "loss_D_fake",  \
              "loss_G_fake", "loss_G_FLIP_l1"]
update_DnG_together = True
G.train()
D.train()
for epo in range(n_epochs):
    for batch_No, (real_img_batch, cond_img_batch) in enumerate(train_loader):
        
        if use_cuda: real_img_batch, cond_img_batch = real_img_batch.cuda(), cond_img_batch.cuda() 
            
        # forward and get loss
        c = 100
        #c = (1-(epo+1)/n_epochs)*100+1 # decay c with epoch
        losses = forward_n_get_loss(real_img_batch, cond_img_batch, G, D, c=c )

        update_D, update_G = (True, True) if update_DnG_together  \
        else ((epo+batch_No)%2!=0, (epo+batch_No)%2==0  )
        
        # update D
        if update_D:
            optimizer_D.zero_grad()
            losses[0].backward(retain_graph=True)
            optimizer_D.step()
            
        # update G
        if update_G:
            optimizer_G.zero_grad()
            losses[1].backward(retain_graph=True)
            optimizer_G.step()
        
    if epo==0 or epo%print_freq==(print_freq-1) or epo==n_epochs-1: 
        et = time.time() 
        loss_vals = map(loss2npval, losses)
        loss_info = dict(zip(loss_names,loss_vals))
        print("[{}] {}, time_cost: {:.2f} min" \
              .format( epo, loss_info, (et-st)/60 ))
        st = et # update st
        # save out
        this_epo_str = str(epo+start_epo).zfill(4) 
        path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Thesis UvT'
        torch.save(G.state_dict(), f"{path}/PyTorch/G_{this_epo_str}")
        torch.save(D.state_dict(), f"{path}/PyTorch/D_{this_epo_str}")
        sample_img(G, train_loader, f"{path}/PyTorch/{this_epo_str}.png")
```

Comment: Would you please provide the relevant code? The error trace alone won't suffice to solve the issue.

Comment: I have added the relevant code, the problem only occurs when I use loss_G

Comment: Could you provide the code where you perform backpropagation (the `backward` call(s))?

Comment: I have added the location where it performs the ```backward``` call

Answer (score 0):

The first issue (this is unrelated to the error which I will come to later) is that you are using `prob_fake` on the BCE loss to compute the generator loss. However `prob_fake` is detached from the generator. This means the gradient won't backpropagate to the generator and it will never train. Instead, you should be inferring the fake (generated) instance through the discriminator without detaching, *i.e.* `D(fake_pair)`.

The second issue is that you performing two backpropagation and steps, which means the first one is on the discriminator. This means the discriminator's weights will have changed before you backpropagate the generator loss `loss_G`. This means you need to infer `loss_G_fake` *using the updated discriminator weights*.

One way to prevent such side effect is to backpropagate on both the losses and step both optimizers at the same time only *after*.

Comment: I found the main problem, the SSH server updated my torchvision. By downgrading this one back to 0.4.0 the issue is resolved! Thank you for your suggestion, I have taken them into account before retraining the network!